# Laravel API - Argument 1 passed to TokenGuard::__construct() must implement interface UserProvider

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, authentication

REST-API in Laravel 8 using [API Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication#configuration).

**Introduction**

I have `Analytics` Model Authenticable to authenticate the request in web rather than using default `User` Model  with corresponding `analytics` and `user` table table. I have migrated `api_token` field in `analytics` table. However, I'm getting below error in response while accessing the API route in POSTMAN.

**Response**

```
{
"message": "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\\Auth\\TokenGuard::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\UserProvider, null given, called in source\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager.php on line 162",
"exception": "TypeError",
}
```

**source\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 162**

```
    public function createTokenDriver($name, $config)
    {
        $guard = new TokenGuard(
            $this->createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null),
            $this->app['request'],
            $config['input_key'] ?? 'api_token',
            $config['storage_key'] ?? 'api_token',
            $config['hash'] ?? false  // **** This is line 162 **** //
        );
```

I tried changing line 162 as `$config['hash'] ?? true` but still getting same error.

> **Note:** The `Analytics` and `User` Model are **Authenticable**. While I have the `api_token` field in the `analytics` table

**Request:**

I'm sending `GET` instance of HTTP Request on endpoint
`http://example.com/api/user?api_token=token(this is unhashed token)`

**Below is the following configuration.**

`route/api.php`

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

The `Analytics` and `User` Model are follow:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Notification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\AnalyticsResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Analytics extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new AnalyticsResetPassword($token));
    }

    protected $table = "analytics";

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'mobile', api_token', ];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'api_token', 'remember_token', ];
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', ];

    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token',];

    protected $casts = ['email_verified_at' => 'datetime',];
}
```

The `guard` and `provider` array in `config/auth.php` configuration file:

```
    'guards' => [
        
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'analytics' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'analytics',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'user',
            'hash' => true,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'analytics' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Analytics::class,
        ],
    ],
```

The token generating method in Controller

```
    public function token(Request $request)
    {
        $token = Str::random(60);
        $user = Auth::user();
        $user->api_token = hash('sha256', $token);
        $user->save();
        return redirect('/analytics/security')->with('success', 'Token Generated Successfully!')->with("token" , $token);
    }
```

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem? can you please share it ? i too have similar problem , tried to change "guards.api.provider" to "analytics" with no luck

Answer (score 0):

```php
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'user',
    'hash' => true,
],
```

I think the problem is the provider property within this guard configuration, as there is no entry for `user` within the `providers` - you only have `users` and `analytics`